# Iterators and range based for loops

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, containers

I'm trying to understand iterators and different ways to iterate over elements in different containers. What's the difference between these two options?

```
for(auto it = myArray.begin(); it < myArray.end(); it++){
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
```

```
for(auto it = myArray.begin(); it != myArray.end(); it++){
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
```

When using the second option my editor suggests using a range based for loop in stead, which made me realise I don't know the difference.

```
for(int & it : myArray){
            std::cout << it << std::endl;
        }
```

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't work with every container but only for containers with random access iterators (like e.g. `std::array` and `std::vector`). Your second snippet will work with all containers. Hence, the range loop resembles rather the second. FYI: [Iterator categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) and [Range based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: I see, but why? Like what actually happens in the first snippet versus the other?

Comment: the first snippet uses `< BiggestValue`, the second uses `!= BiggestValue`. There are no values for which those expressions differ in result

Comment: The definition of < for iterators in general is if you can increment one and it eventually reaches the other, but C++ chooses to not define what it means to increment an iterator equal to the end of a sequence, so there's no general, safe way of doing `<`.

Comment: vector iterators have `<` because they are approximately pointers, and pointers have a numeric representation

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between these two options?

Not all types of input iterators are comparable using the `<` operator (only [random-access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) are, but not all iterators are random-access). All input iterators are comparable using the `==` and/or `!=` operator, though.

> When using the second option my editor suggests using a range based for loop instead

As you should.  A [range-`for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) uses iterators internally, similar to your second `for` loop.  The loop variable is the *dereferenced value*, not the iterator itself.  A range-for loop does not expose access to its internal iterators.